# out.width option in knitr::include_graphics() creates unknown float option in tex file

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

When I add `out.width = '50%'` in the chunk options, the `knitr::include_function()` creates a `\begin{figure}{H}` line of code when it is run via `book_down::render_book()`.

Basically, I want to reduce the size of the image (png or pdf) but neither the `dpi` or `fig.width` options are having any effect.

This `{H}` float option creates a problem for LaTeX; basically, it is unknown.
Yihui, you're my only hope!

Comment: add `header-includes:  - \usepackage{float}` to your YAML header where  the part after the colon start indented in a new line.

Comment: Yes! It works. I tested different places for your input until I finally realized index.Rmd was the right one. Thank you Martin.